# How is the magnetization $M$ of a material measured?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, history

In a linear material under the influence of an external field $H$, magnetization $M$ is given by
\begin{align}
{\bf M} = \chi {\bf H},
\end{align}
so that the total field inside the material is ${\bf B} = (1+\chi){\bf H}$.

As I understand, some modern techniques for measuring the magnetization ${\bf M}$ of a material rely on the [SQUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID) apparatus, such as in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep45945), which in turn rely on the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect).

I would like to know what other techniques are available for this measurement, specially techniques that rely on simple physical mechanisms.

In particular, I would also like to know what techniques were historically first developed for this task (e.g. what they used before the discovery of the Aharonov-Bohm effect).

Comment: [3.1 Measuring magnetisation by force/induction](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/quantum-spins/sites/quantum-spins/files/MPM-Part3.pdf)

Comment: That's a nice source, thanks! I had never heard of the Gouy Method, seems pretty interesting. Eq. (3.5) is missing for me though (it's blank, LATEX formatting error maybe?).

Comment: There is more, a part 1 and a part 2 which might be of interest?  Also a [list of formulae which has the missing equation.](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/quantum-spins/sites/quantum-spins/files/MPM-Part3-eq.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to take a look at those also, where can I find them?

Comment: Click on the link that I have posted.

Comment: I meant about the part 1 and 2, the link redirects to part 3's formulas

Comment: [Part 1](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/quantum-spins/sites/quantum-spins/files/MPM-Part1.pdf) and [Part 2](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/quantum-spins/sites/quantum-spins/files/MPM-Part2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much!